# Autoencoder make spectrogram important parts more pronounced with a "log loss"

Tags: tensorflow, autoencoders, unsupervised-learning, audio-processing

Hi I want to create a neural network that essentially picks out the most pronounced parts of a spectrogram.

Assume this is the True spectrogram:

`[0.0, 0.25, 0.95, 0.1, 0.0, ...]`

I want the auto encoder output to tend towards outputs like this:

`[0.0, 0.05, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...]`

I essentially want to punish the neural network more for getting larger values more incorrect.

`True 0.2, Predicted 0.1`

`True 0.9, Predicted 0.8` <---- Far greater loss

Since I don't care about background sounds this will make the important parts of the spectrogram more pronounced.

> Will this work? What should I use?

Comment: From what you have posted, this looks like a task more easily solved with a simple filter.  Is there a reason you are preferring a NN?

Comment: Because within the spectrogram there also random background noises that I add which will be removed @DavidHoelzer

Comment: Why not do a simple SVD to remove the noise?